# What's the meaning of java.util.@Nullable?

Tags: java

I'm reading [the code of Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/491fe70163262b0da469da4fa7856a0aa5b9ce09/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Optional.java#L141-L144) where I found the annotation `java.util.@Nullable` in some code. I know the meaning of `@Nullable`, but I don't understand this one. In particular, I can't find a class called `Nullable` in the package `java.util`.
Please, someone tell me what's the meaning of this `java.util.@Nullable`:

```java
public static <T> java.util.@Nullable Optional<T> toJavaUtil(
    @Nullable Optional<T> googleOptional) {
  return googleOptional == null ? null : googleOptional.toJavaUtil();
}
```

Comment: Source code for those interested ~ https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Optional.java#L141

Comment: `@Nullable` here actually comes from the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) ~ https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/Nullable.html. I'm not familiar with this syntax though where you append an annotation to a package name

Comment: I wonder if this might just be a weird Java-syntax-ism. In particular, could this basically just mean `public static <T> @Nullable java.util.Optional<T> toJavaUtil`, but that Java just doesn't let you write it that way?

Comment: @JosephSible that's what it's looking like to me too. The return type of the method is `java.util.Optional`

Comment: @JosephSible `public static <T> @Nullable java.util.Optional<T> toJavaUtil` is indeed not possible, but there is no reason to use the FQN of `Optional` when the import already exists.

Comment: @Tom There's another `Optional` in scope there.

Comment: @JosephSible And no import, I thought I saw one. My mistake.

Comment: thanks guys ,i found this in Checker Framework.
```@Nullable java.util.List

The correct Java syntax to write an annotation on a fully-qualified type name is to put the annotation on the simple name part, as in java.util.@Nullable List. But, it’s usually better to add import java.util.List to your source file, so that you can just write @Nullable List.```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The line `public static <T> java.util.@Nullable Optional<T> toJavaUtil` is written like this, because the usual style `public static <T> @Nullable java.util.Optional<T> toJavaUtil` is invalid. This is defined in the [JLS §9.7.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4):

> **It is a compile-time error if an annotation of type T applies to a type (or any part of a type) in a type context, and T is applicable in type contexts, and the annotation is not admissible.**
>
> For example, assume an annotation type TA which is meta-annotated with just `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`. The terms `@TA java.lang.Object` and `java.@TA lang.Object` are illegal because the simple name to which @TA is closest is classified as a package name. On the other hand, `java.lang.@TA Object` is legal.

The type declaration of `org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual@Nullable` is:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
```

So it is applying to this rule.

That this structure doesn't break the execution, since package `java.util` and class name `Optional` were split, can be seen when we look at the compiled code using `javap -c [compiled class name]`:

```
class just.a.test.Main {
  just.a.test.Main();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1          // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static <T> java.util.Optional<T> toJavaUtil(blub.Optional<T>);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: ifnonnull     8
       4: aconst_null
       5: goto          12
       8: aload_0
       9: invokevirtual #2          // Method blub/Optional.toJavaUtil:()Ljava/util/Optional;
      12: areturn
}
```

<sup>*(`blub.Optional` is a local class where I copied the Guava code in, in order to get a minimal example to de-/compile)*</sup>

As you can see, the annotation doesn't exist there anymore. It is only a marker for the compiler to prevent a warning when the method returns null (and a hint for the source code readers), but it won't be included in the compiled code.

---

This compiler error also applies to variables like:

```
private @Nullable2 java.util.Optional<?> o;
```

But can become acceptable when the annotation additionally gets the target type  `ElementType.FIELD`, as written in the same JLS clause:

> If TA is additionally meta-annotated with `@Target(ElementType.FIELD)`, then the term `@TA java.lang.Object` is legal in locations which are both declaration and type contexts, such as a field declaration `@TA java.lang.Object f;`. Here, @TA is deemed to apply to the declaration of f (and not to the type java.lang.Object) because TA is applicable in the field declaration context.

Answer (score 12):

When using annotations, this is the syntax that is used when you want to write fully qualified name for the type, instead of adding import statement.

Quoting from the [checker framework manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/):

> The correct Java syntax to write an annotation on a fully-qualified
>   type name is to put the annotation on the simple name part, as in
>   java.util.@Nullable List. But, it’s usually better to add import
>   java.util.List to your source file, so that you can just write
>   @Nullable List.

It is also mentioned on page 2 of **JSR308** specification which can be downloaded [here](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/annotations-2013_03_15-edr3-spec/). It says:

> A type annotation appears before the type’s simple name, as in
>   @NonNull String or java.lang.@NonNull String.

Answer (score 7):

The strange bit here really is the unfamiliar syntax for applying a `ElementType.TYPE_USE`-targeted annotation.
If you check the [Nullable](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/Nullable.html)'s docs, you'll see the unfamiliar target:

```
...
@Target(value={TYPE_USE,TYPE_PARAMETER})
<public @interface Nullable
...
```

This annotation is used right before the simple name of the annotated type, like in both of the following:

```
public static <T> @Nullable Optional<T> toJavaUtil
public static <T> java.util.@Nullable Optional<T> toJavaUtil
```

---

I didn't know what the use of this kind of target was, so after a quick read, I got to this simple example, which picks up return type metadata using an annotation that has that target:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@interface InterceptedReturnValue {
    boolean value() default true;
}
```

And processed it using:

```
public java.lang.@InterceptedReturnValue(true) String testMethod(String param) {
    return null;
}

public @InterceptedReturnValue(false) String testMethod(int param) {
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Method m = Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("testMethod", String.class);
    if(m.getAnnotatedReturnType().isAnnotationPresent(InterceptedReturnValue.class)) {
        InterceptedReturnValue config = m.getAnnotatedReturnType()
                .getAnnotation(InterceptedReturnValue.class);

        if(config.value()) {
            //logging return value enabled
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure many useful frameworks, such as checkerframework, make the most appropriate use of `ElementType.TYPE_USE`